# How can i get the value of labels textvariable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can i get the value of `textvariable` from `town_label1` and `street_label1` after i pick country in combobox? F.E for Belgium `town_label1` should be 'Brussels' and for `street_label1` should be "red_boulevard".

when i print it in funtcion works perfectly, but i need those dynamic values outside of a function

Gives me PyVAR1 when i use `.get()` method and when i try to print function asks me for func argument. I used `lambda` in `.bind()`, but it allows only 4 arguments and i need more than that, since "town" and "street" will not be the only keys later.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

#DICTIONARIES#
materialDict = {"": {"town": 0, "street": 0},
                "Belgium": {"town": "Brussels", "street": "red_boulevard"},
                "Germany": {"town": "Bremen", "street": "green_boulevard"}}


#FUNCTION#

def selected(func):
    a = materialDict [main.get()]["town"]
    town.set(a)
    c = materialDict [main.get()]["street"]
    street.set(c)


#WINDOWLOOP#
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x125")

#VARIABLES#

main = tk.StringVar()
town = tk.StringVar()
street = tk.StringVar()


#COMBOBOXES#
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, height=5, state="readonly", values=list(materialDict.keys()), textvariable=main)
combobox.place(x=10, y=10, width=130)
combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', func=selected)


#LABELS#
town_label = tk.Label(root, text='town:')
town_label.place(x=150, y=10, width=70, height=20)

street_label = tk.Label(root, text='street:')
street_label.place(x=150, y=70, width=70, height=20)

town_label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=town)
town_label1.place(x=155, y=30, width=100, height=20)

street_label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=street)
street_label1.place(x=155, y=90, width=100, height=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"Gives me PyVAR1 when i use .get() method"_ - what line of code are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `town_label1.cget("textvariable")` it will return the internal name of the variable rather than the variable itself. Tkinter provides a method named `getvar` to get the value of a variable by name.

```
varname = town_label1.cget("textvariable")
value = town_label1.getvar(varname)
print(f"value: {value}")
```